# Python - Get user to input 10 numbers and then display only the prime numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need your help if possible. I am very new to Python, but I've got a good understanding in C#, java and now have started learning python as part of my learning program. I am stuck with one of my tasks to do and I can't get any help as no one that I know uses python.

My task is : 
"Find the prime numbers from the given list of 10 numbers. User should input 10 numbers"
Could anyone help me please? Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried ? Please provide some code.

Comment: give us some code and more rules, for example the possible range of the numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At very simple i make this program for you as per your requirement that user must enter 10 numbers and program finds either it is prime or not.

try this:

```
for i in range(0, 10):
    num = int(input('Enter Number:'))
    if num > 1:
        # check for factors
        for i in range(2, num):
            if (num % i) == 0:
                print(num, "is not a prime number")
                print(i, "times", num // i, "is", num)
                break
        else:
            print(num, "is a prime number")

    # if input number is less than
    # or equal to 1, it is not prime
    else:
        print(num, "is not a prime number")
```

**Note:** In a for loop a take input from user 10 times if you want to take inputs in the starting then you can also to that and you can then run a loop o that list. Choice is yours!

Answer (score 0):

```
import math

def is_prime(n):
    if n % 2 == 0 and n > 2:
        return False
    return all(n % i for i in range(3, int(math.sqrt(n)) + 1, 2))

for i in range(10):
    number = input("Choose number #%s : " % i)
    if is_prime(int(number)):
        print("%s is prime" % number)
    else:
        print("%s is not prime" % number)
```

Comment: The question is asking for python3 answers as you may see in the tag, your answer, however, is in python2.

Comment: A little harsh to downvote for parenthesis around `print` but well, code updated and up and running on python3

Comment: It is temporary as long as you fix it, just trying to follow the rules :^)

Answer (score -1):

You need a function isPrime(n) which check if n is a prime number like this:
`import math.sqrt
def isPrime(n):
       for i in range(2,int(sqrt(n))+1):
              if n%i==0:
                  return False
       return True` 
 Then, you just get the input numbers (int(input("Enter a number")), you store your numbers and you use the function in all the numbers of the list.

Answer (score -1):

To get an input of 10 Numbers just put input() in a for loop like this:

```
for i in range (0,11):
    input("Number")
```

in addition to that you need a function which calls whether your number is a prime number

```
def isPrime(n):
   for i in range(2,int(sqrt(n))+1):
          if n%i==0:
              return False
   return True
```

Answer (score -1):

```
from math import sqrt; from itertools import count, islice
import sys

def is_prime(n):
    return n > 1 and all(n%i for i in islice(count(2), int(sqrt(n)-1)))

def primer(*args):
    return '-'.join([str(x) for x in args if is_prime(x)])

while True:
    try:
        user_input = input('Enter any amount of numbers seperating them with a comma; or enter quit to quit: ')
        if any(user_input==x for x in ("quit", "q", "exit", "e")):
            sys.exit()
        our_list = [int(x) for x in user_input.split(',')]
        print(primer(*our_list))
    except ValueError:
        print('Please only enter numbers')
```

Normally you should try first, have broken code and then ask; but hey I'm bored so I made an exception for you, here is the whole code. :3

Comment: Thank you for your effort I really appreciate it, only thing is with your code is that it doesn't set fixed number of inputs from user(10). However functionallity is perfectly fine. Thank you again for you effort, and I'll make sure to add my code in future questions!